# How to loop the images in apex class which are presented in the zip folder of static resource

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to use some images in VF Page from the static resource but i want the images to be added dynamically based on the images list in the zip file of static resource.

For that, i have used this code in my apex class

```
public List<String> imageList{get;set;}
public DemoWorkClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    string imaURL;
    for(integer i = 1; i <= (imageslist); i++){
        imaURL = 'images/'+i+'.TIF';
    }
    imageList.add(imaURL);
}
```

and called this list of string to the VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="account" extensions="DemoWorkClass" renderAs="PDF">
<body>
    <table>
        <td>
            <apex:variable var="imgVar" value="{!imageList}"/>
            <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.ImagesDemo,imgVar)}"/>
        </td>
    </table>
</body>
```

**Note:
I have to get the images from the Static Resource Only**

Please give me the suggestions,

**--> In getting the number of images in the zip file of static resource**

**--> Storing the images in the list and to be present them in the VF Page**

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You used apex:variable.  You should be using apex:repeat.

Comment: Yeah I tried that apex:repeat too...
but still it is not showing any result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of images in the zip, you will have to parse the zip. A zip file can not be parsed with simple JavaScript. There is simply no native function that can ope ZIP files. However there are some additional libraries which can help you achieve this.

To implement this I have used jsZIP (https://stuk.github.io/jszip/)

jsUtilZip to get file from Resource : https://stuk.github.io/jszip-utils/dist/jszip-utils.js

```
<apex:page>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jsZip,'jsZip/dist/jszip.min.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jsZip,'jsZip/dist/jsziputil.js')}"/>
<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.ansPKB_Asset,'scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js')}"></script>

<script>

    <div class="image-div">
    </div>

var files;

$(function(){
    //var zip = new JSZip();
    files = [];

    //this resource has two files
    var resourceURL = '{!URLFOR($Resource.ansPKB_jQuery)}';

    JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(resourceURL, function(err, data) {
      if(err) {
        throw err; // or handle err
      }

      var zip = new JSZip(data);

      for (var fileName in zip.files) {
          files.push(fileName)
      }
      console.log(files); //["abc.jpg","pqr.jpg"]
    }); 
})

</script>
```

To include these files in your image source tag, just iterate over it and create a String

```
var imageString ='';
for(index=0;files.length;index++)
     imageString += '<img src="url({!URLFOR($Resource.resourceName,\''+files[index]+'\')})" />';

$(".image-div").append(imageString);
```

Comment: Where is ansPKB_Asset and ansPKB_jQuery?
i didn't find it anywhere
Please let me know...

Comment: Those are my static resources 1. ansPKB_jQuery is the jquery and asset is zip folder with files

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply but i cannot get the perfect understanding of this code as because i am very new to this technology.

Could you please tell me this one with some kind of explanation...
Thanks in advance....

Comment: Especially on this part of script

`<script>

    <div class="image-div">
    </div>

var files;

$(function(){
    //var zip = new JSZip();
    files = [];

    //this resource has two files
    var resourceURL = '{!URLFOR($Resource.ansPKB_jQuery)}';

    JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(resourceURL, function(err, data) {
      if(err) {
        throw err; // or handle err
      }

      var zip = new JSZip(data);

      for (var fileName in zip.files) {
          files.push(fileName)
      }
      console.log(files); //["abc.jpg","pqr.jpg"]
    }); 
})

</script>`